# Создать многомерный массив из обычного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив на входе

```
blocks:[
  {
    value: 1,
    parent: null
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    parent: 0
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    parent: 1
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    parent: 2
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    parent: 1
  }
]
```

Нужно его преобразовать в многомерный массив такого вида

```
{
  value: 1,
  parent: null,
  children: [
    {
      value: 2,
      parent: 0,
      children: [
        {
          value: 3,
          parent: 1,
          children: [
            {
              value: 4,
              parent: 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          value: 5,
          parent: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать на js?

Comment: Поясните, почему `value: 4` должно оказаться именно в этом месте, и по какому принципу `parent: 2` у него меняется на `parent: 1`?

Comment: @Yaant Извиняюсь, допустил ошибку, исправил.

Comment: parent это index объекта, решил не вставлять id как ключевое значение

Comment: Ага, теперь стало логичнее. Но тогда зачем в результирующем объекте вообще нужно поле `parent`, если родитель однозначно определяется самой его структурой?

Comment: @Yaant согласен можно его убрать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let blocks = [{
    value: 1,
    parent: null
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    parent: 0
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    parent: 1
  },
  {
    value: 4,
    parent: 2
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    parent: 1
  }
];

let res = []; 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blocks))  // чтобы исходный массив остался неизменным, создаем его копию, далее работаем с ней.
  .forEach((item, i, arr) => {
    if (item.parent == null) { // элементы без родителя добавляем в результирующий массив
      res.push(item);
    } else {
      let parent = arr[item.parent]; // находим родительский элемент в исходном массиве (вернее, в его копии)
      if (!parent.children) parent.children = []; 
      parent.children.push(item); // и добавляем к нему дочерний элемент
    }
    delete item.parent; // удаляем поле parent
  });
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Во первых - это не многомерный массив, а дерево `tree`
Во вторых преобразуй данные через метод `Array.map()` к формату `{ id, parentId }`, так как `{ value, parent }` не совсем удачный нэйминг. После этого заюзай эту функцию и ты получишь нужный результат.

```js
function list_to_tree(list) {
    var map = {}, node, roots = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        map[list[i].id] = i; // initialize the map
        list[i].children = []; // initialize the children
    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        node = list[i];
        if (node.parentId !== "0") {
            // if you have dangling branches check that map[node.parentId] exists
            list[map[node.parentId]].children.push(node);
        } else {
            roots.push(node);
        }
    }
    return roots;
};

var entries = [
    {
        "id": "12",
        "parentId": "0"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "10",
        "parentId": "12"
    },
];

console.log(list_to_tree(entries));
```